# aws cognito does not fetch all users

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito

I use aws Cognito for my application as userpool. Now I have the issue that not all users were fetched from AWS.

Some useres which were successfully verified are not in the user list. What could be the issue in this case? Thanks in advance.

```
const params = {
    UserPoolId: 'eu-central-1_xasasdasdasd', /* required */
    Limit: 0
}


return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    awsSDKAuth().listUsers(params, (err, data) => {
        if (err) {
            console.error(err);
            reject(err);
        } else {
```

Comment: Can u plz share code segments plz

Comment: Thats the code I use (added above)

Comment: Can you apply the knowledge of this https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito-user-identity-pools/latest/APIReference/API_ListUsers.html

Hope this is good enough to solve your issue.
Limit: 0, Why do you keep that 0 instead of 60 (max value).

Comment: And what do I do when I have more than 60 users?

Comment: It is expected to read the doc link again. Hint: "PaginationToken".